# Can PyCharm show the line where an error occurs?

Tags: pycharm

I just started trying out PyCharm Community, and I am surprised to see that when an error occurs in code all I get is a line in the Console window that shows the error type, source file name and line number.  That means I need to navigate to the file and line number, which is very inefficient.

I have worked with Wing, VS Code and VS Community, and all three show error lines by default.  There must some way to enable that in PyCharm, but I haven’t found it, even after research.

Is there a way for PyCharm to show the error line in the source file, or is it only able to show me the location in the Console window and I have to navigate there myself?

Thanks.

Comment: I am not using Community so there might be a difference, but for me the exception includes clickable links and you are immediately at the line. Is it the same for you? https://imgur.com/GnwJDt4.png

Comment: Yes there is a hyperlink to the file.  I can work with that if there's no other way, but it's not the most efficient.  Showing the line in source by default is much better.

Comment: Here is a simple example. Does it also not work here? https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/guide/tutorials/visual_pytest/jump_to_error/ Are you catching and printing the error or is it a "natural" throw?

Comment: This error is not a throw, I didn't expect it.  It's a missing file.  Nothing exciting.